# Reading in from a file with getline() having multiple info on one line get invalid argument error

Tags: c++, arrays, file

hello folks im still a beginner to c++ so i apologize in advance.
okay so some context is this is a hw assignment for my class we have to make a an array that holds all the books that are being read in from the a txt file then organize them by hashing. the part that im stuck on is reading in the data i cant seem to get it right. the error occurs in load table function, it reads the first line and i put the cout stuff under it to test it out and it does print the first book out but after it throws a invalid argument error.

Input file:

```
116807#A Tale of Two Cities#Charles Dickens#3.73#9.99#1  
111272#The Iliad#Homer#2.78#9.99#10  
164440#The Great Gatsby#F. Scott Fitzgerald#4.92#9.99#8  
122503#Pride and Prejudice#Jane Austen#3.29#8.99#3  
144303#Little Lord Fauntleroy#Frances Hodgson Burnett#3.09#9.99#1  
170933#Alice's Adventures in Wonderland#Lewis Carroll#2.78#9.99#6  
199097#The Awakening#Kate Chopin#4.12#8.99#1  
177633#Robinson Crusoe#Daniel Defoe#3.49#7.99#2  
111967#Little Women#Louisa May Alcott#4.93#7.99#6  
191745#Emma#Jane Austen#4.91#7.99#8  
135001#Sense and Sensibility#Jane Austen#4.08#8.99#9  
171490#The Wonderful Wizard of Oz#L. Frank Baum#2.96#7.99#4  
127722#Lorna Doone#R. D. Blackmore#3.49#9.99#2  
106853#Jane Eyre#Charlotte Brontë#2.08#7.99#4  
160298#Wuthering Heights#Emily Brontë#3.35#8.99#6  
189814#The Secret Garden#Frances Hodgson Burnett#4.36#9.99#10  
124115#Tales from the Arabian Nights#Richard Francis Burton#3.29#8.99#8  
134195#Through the Looking-Glass#Lewis Carroll#2.04#7.99#9  
182188#Don Quixote of La Mancha#Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra#4.05#8.99#3  
131566#The Man Who Was Thursday#G.K. Chesterton#3.37#9.99#5  
151501#The Napoleon of Notting Hill#G.K. Chesterton#2.71#9.99#8  
119358#The Moonstone#Wilkie Collins#3.97#7.99#5  
121609#The Woman in White#Wilkie Collins#4.45#7.99#6  
166298#Heart of Darkness#Joseph Conrad#3.99#9.99#3  
100260#Lord Jim#Joseph Conrad#3.94#8.99#6  
125968#The Deerslayer#James Fenimore Cooper#4.3#8.99#3  
197942#The Last of the Mohicans#James Fenimore Cooper#3.82#8.99#8  
133821#The Red Badge of Courage#Stephen Crane#2.12#7.99#2  
148590#The Fortunes and Misfortunes#Defoe#2.38#7.99#7             
119790#Bleak House#Charles Dickens#4.79#9.99#7  
197972#A Christmas Carol#Charles Dickens#3.95#7.99#5  
145223#David Copperfield#Charles Dickens#3.6#8.99#7  
136123#Great Expectations#Charles Dickens#4.13#9.99#9  
129094#Oliver Twist#Charles Dickens#2.44#8.99#5  
125226#The Brothers Karamazov#Fyodor Dostoyevsky#2.63#7.99#5  
159590#Crime and Punishment#Fyodor Dostoyevsky#4.59#8.99#8  
197385#The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes#Arthur Conan Doyle#3.72#7.99#8  
142385#The Hound of the Baskervilles#Arthur Conan Doyle#3.85#8.99#1  
128144#The Count of Monte Cristo#Alexandre Dumas#4.35#7.99#6  
163534#The Man in the Iron Mask#Alexandre Dumas#3.11#7.99#3  
175244#Middlemarch#George Eliot#3.18#9.99#3  
101815#Silas Marner#George Eliot#3.33#9.99#8  
189553#The Diary of a Nobody#George Grossmith and Weedon Grossmith#3.25#9.99#3  
130211#Allan Quatermain#Henry Rider Haggard#2.77#8.99#6  
137335#King Solomon's Mines#Henry Rider Haggard#4.95#7.99#8  
197439#Far from the Madding Crowd#Thomas Hardy#3.31#7.99#2  
168872#Tess of the D'Urbervilles#Thomas Hardy#4.94#8.99#6  
139789#The Scarlet Letter#Nathaniel Hawthorne#3.15#8.99#10  
115680#Tanglewood Tales for Girls and Boys#Nathaniel Hawthorne#3.55#7.99#4  
133502#A Wonder-Book for Girls and Boys#Nathaniel Hawthorne#4.08#7.99#2  
177844#The Four Million#O. Henry#4.08#9.99#2  
154849#The Odyssey#Homer#2.31#7.99#5  
195419#The Prisoner of Zenda#Anthony Hope#3.09#7.99#10  
195223#The Hunchback of Notre-Dame#Victor Hugo#3.6#7.99#6  
147317#Les Misérables#Victor Hugo#2#9.99#5  
160597#The Sketch Book of Geoffrey Crayon#Washington Irving#2.04#9.99#1  
141976#The Aspern Papers#Henry James#4.54#7.99#5  
148381#The Turn of the Screw#Henry James#3.65#9.99#10  
178209#The Jungle Book#Rudyard Kipling#3.53#8.99#8  
164607#Kim#Rudyard Kipling#4.22#7.99#7  
170053#The Man Who Would Be King#Rudyard Kipling#3.3#9.99#1  
160444#The Phantom of the Opera#Gaston Leroux#4.85#8.99#9  
108155#The Call of the Wild#Jack London#2.57#9.99#9  
158266#White Fang#Jack London#4.11#9.99#5  
174819#The Princess and Curdie#George MacDonald#2.33#9.99#1  
148762#The Princess and the Goblin#George MacDonald#3.97#7.99#9  
160589#The Prince#Niccolò Machiavelli#2.77#8.99#9  
161200#Moby Dick#Herman Melville#3.6#8.99#8  
145480#Utopia#Thomas More#3.55#7.99#8  
141238#Rights of Man#Thomas Paine#2.26#8.99#8  
161113#Tales of Mystery & Imagination#Edgar Allan Poe#4.93#9.99#5  
168418#Ivanhoe#Sir Walter Scott#2.85#7.99#6  
176563#Waverley#Sir Walter Scott#2.17#8.99#10  
162967#Black Beauty#Anna Sewell#2.69#7.99#4    
104473#Hamlet#William Shakespeare#2.48#8.99#9  
163459#King Lear#William Shakespeare#2.3#9.99#3  
100973#MacBeth#William Shakespeare#3.97#8.99#1  
135231#A Midsummer Night's Dream#Shakespeare#3.03#9.99#1  
162533#Othello, The Moor of Venice#Shakespeare#4.03#9.99#1  
123934#Romeo and Juliet#hakespeare#4.79#9.99#5  
133549#The Taming of the Shrew#Shakespeare#3.49#9.99#1  
115879#The Tempest#William Shakespeare#3.7#7.99#4  
173650#Frankenstein#Mary Shelley#3.29#9.99#7  
110299#The Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde#Robert#2.21#9.99#5  
168244#Kidnapped#Robert Louis Stevenson#4.96#7.99#5  
191560#Dracula#Bram Stoker#4.51#9.99#4  
189551#Uncle Tom's Cabin#Harriet Beecher Stowe#2.05#7.99#9  
159274#Gulliver's Travels#Jonathan Swift#4.13#9.99#6  
122012#Vanity Fair#William Makepeace Thackeray#2.88#9.99#9  
181550#Walden#Henry David Thoreau#2.95#8.99#2  
135690#Anna Karenina#Leo Tolstoy#2.1#9.99#4  
109565#War and Peace#Leo Tolstoy#4.42#9.99#3  
107307#Barchester Towers#Anthony Trollope#2.1#9.99#10  
143127#The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn#Twain#4.87#9.99#6  
116641#The Adventures of Tom Sawyer#twain#2.48#9.99#6  
115974#A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court#Twain#4.73#9.99#2  
109239#Journey to the Center of the Earth#Jules Verne#3.05#8.99#4  
154189#20,000 Leagues Under the Sea#Jules Verne#3.56#8.99#1  
145898#The Time Machine#H.G. Wells#3.2#7.99#1  
198867#The Age of Innocence#Edith Wharton#2.39#9.99#2  
160811#The Importance of Being Earnest#Oscar Wilde#4.91#8.99#9  
126671#The Picture of Dorian Gray#Oscar Wilde#4.45#7.99#1
```

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct book
{
    int bookid;
    string title;
    string author;
    float cost;
    float price;
    int quantity;
};

int getHashKey(int, int);
void clearTable(book[], int);
void loadTable(book[], int);
void loadBook(book[], book, int);


int main()
{
    int  size;
    cout << "Enter size of table!" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    book * arr = new book[size];

    clearTable(arr, size);
    loadTable(arr, size);
    /*for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i].bookid << endl;
    }*/

    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
int getHashKey(int key, int max_size)
{
    return key % max_size;
}
void clearTable(book arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i].bookid = -1;
    }
}
void loadBook(book arr[], book val, int size)
{
    int key = (val.bookid % size);
    while (arr[key].bookid != -1)
    {
        key = (key + 1) % size;
    }
    arr[key] = val;
}

void loadTable(book arr[], int size)
{
    book tempBook;
    string line;
    char s;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("inventory.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (!myfile.eof())
        {
            //this is the part that reads in the line stopping at the #
            //it reads the first line correct than it throws a invalid 
            //argument error. 
            getline(myfile, line, '#');
            tempBook.bookid = stoi(line);

            getline(myfile, line, '#');
            tempBook.title = line;

            getline(myfile, line, '#');
            tempBook.author = line;

            getline(myfile, line, '#');
            tempBook.cost = stof(line);

            getline(myfile, line, '#');
            tempBook.price = stof(line);

            getline(myfile, line, '#');
            tempBook.quantity = stoi(line);


            cout << tempBook.bookid << endl;
            cout << tempBook.title << endl;
            cout << tempBook.author << endl;
            cout << tempBook.cost << endl;
            cout << tempBook.price << endl;
            cout << tempBook.quantity << endl;







            //add load book


            //loadBook(arr, tempBook, size);


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: [why `while (!myfile.eof())` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Run the program under your debugger, and see what the value of the variable is when it gets the invalid argument error.

Comment: @Barmar Might even be a dupe if there the error happens on last iteration.  OP what does your file look like?

Comment: @NathanOliver I think he said the error happens on the second line, so that would only be if the file is one line long.

Comment: I suspect there's no `#` after the last field on the line, so the last `getline()` should use newline as the delimiter, not `#`.

Comment: @Barmar That would do it.

Comment: @Barmar Might i added the list so you can see it and ive tried getline(myfile, line, '\n');
but it still gives me the error and skips half of the list

Comment: i replaced myfile.eof() with getline(myfile, line) but it seems to skip every other entry

Comment: Can you paste the file as plain text, not an image, so we can copy it for testing?

Comment: Have you figured out which call is reporting invalid argument yet? What did you discover when you ran the program in the debugger? If you haven't, why not?

Comment: @Barmar after the .eof change i get no more errors and sorry ill post the text in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error on the 2nd line happens because the last field of the row doesn't have `#` after it. So the last `getline()` should use `'\n'` as the delimiter, not `'#'`.

When this is fixe, you get an error is happening after reading the last line, because you're using `while (!myfile.eof())`. The EOF condition isn't set until *after* you try to read the file at the end, as explained in [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). So it's reading an empty line, then trying to parse it as a number. You should put the first `getline()` call in the `while()` condition.

The corrected program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct book
{
    int bookid;
    string title;
    string author;
    float cost;
    float price;
    int quantity;
};

int getHashKey(int, int);
void clearTable(book[], int);
void loadTable(book[], int);
void loadBook(book[], book, int);

int main()
{
    int  size;
    cout << "Enter size of table!" << endl;
    cin >> size;
    book * arr = new book[size];

    clearTable(arr, size);
    loadTable(arr, size);
    /*for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i].bookid << endl;
    }*/

    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
int getHashKey(int key, int max_size)
{
    return key % max_size;
}
void clearTable(book arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i].bookid = -1;
    }
}
void loadBook(book arr[], book val, int size)
{
    int key = (val.bookid % size);
    while (arr[key].bookid != -1)
    {
        key = (key + 1) % size;
    }
    arr[key] = val;
}

void loadTable(book arr[], int size)
{
    book tempBook;
    string line;
    char s;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("inventory.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line, '#'))
        {
            tempBook.bookid = stoi(line);

            getline(myfile, line, '#');
            tempBook.title = line;

            getline(myfile, line, '#');
            tempBook.author = line;

            getline(myfile, line, '#');
            tempBook.cost = stof(line);

            getline(myfile, line, '#');
            tempBook.price = stof(line);

            getline(myfile, line, '\n');
            tempBook.quantity = stoi(line);


            cout << tempBook.bookid << endl;
            cout << tempBook.title << endl;
            cout << tempBook.author << endl;
            cout << tempBook.cost << endl;
            cout << tempBook.price << endl;
            cout << tempBook.quantity << endl;

            //add load book

            //loadBook(arr, tempBook, size);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bargar Thanks you have been a great help and  thank you for your time!